# How to improve OpenCV edge detection accuracy?

Tags: python, opencv

Lately, I have been working on a project that involves giving a ruler as a reference and then estimating the length of a steel pipe. But the edge detection process is not very satisfactory, so I want to know how I can improve the edge detection results？ Here is my code and the processed image.

[image]

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def getContours(img,cThr=[65,130],showCanny=False):         
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)           
    imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgGray,(3,3),1)              
    imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgBlur,cThr[0],cThr[1])           
    kernel = np.ones((2,2))
    imgDial = cv2.dilate(imgCanny,kernel,iterations=1)
    imgThre = cv2.erode(imgDial,kernel,iterations=1)
    if showCanny: cv2.imshow('Canny',imgThre)
```

The edge detection process is not very satisfactory,  I want to know how I can improve the edge detection results？

Comment: I think you need to focus on image quality better lighting, and higher resolution. For example, when you arrange your lens properly an industrial camera with a lens can get you sharper images with respect to an auto-focus USB camera. Also applying light from different angles and taking pictures then combining these images will amplify the edges in the image.